# Running game server and webserver on EC2

Tags: web-server, performance, amazon-ec2

Hey guys, I have a webhost, and an EC2 server (to run a game server on).
The problem is that I want to access/modify the EC2's files with php admin programs.
I looked into a lot of options to just have the webhost communicate with the EC2 server (ssh, etc), but none of them panned out.
My question is if I were to install a lightweight webserver (think lighttpd) on my EC2 server, how badly would it hurt the game server's performance?  I was leaning away from this solution, even though the webserver (on the EC2 server) wouldn't get many hits (less than a 100 a day).

Thanks for your thoughts,
Max

Comment: EC2 will add up at $0.10/hour == $72/mo.  Consider Linode, or perhaps a cheap dedicated server.

Comment: There are multiple instances on Amazon EC2. I'm getting away with ~$10 a month.

Comment: @user33903 Yeah, EC2 is pretty expensive, but atm I can't find something as flexible.

Comment: Have you reserved your instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the webserver runs heavy duty stuff I doubt it'll have any impact at all.
Idle webservers use very little resources (my, mostly idle, nginx tags in at about 3mb total RAM).

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping to here, bonus question, which server do you use? (Apache, etc)

Comment: [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) together with [PHP-FPM](http://php-fpm.org/) running on an Ubuntu 10.10 (Micro instance)